# Django - staticfiles directory keeps getting created

Tags: django, static-files

There is a directory called "staticfiles" that gets created each time I run the django development web server:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

[image]

I have the staticfiles as one of my apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
#    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

A few other "static files" settings, which are probably unrelated:

```
# Static files
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # Url for static file serving
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),] # Search directories for static files (otherwise, engine only searches within app directories
```

Why does this `staticfiles` directory keeps getting created?  It's always empty.

Comment: where are you defining the static_root setting?

Comment: I'm not setting that parameter.  Do I need to?  What does it do?

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `static` dirs in each app will be copied to `STATIC_ROOT` when you execute `collectstatic`. You need to configure your production server (nginx or uwsgi etc.) for transmition static files from `STATIC_ROOT`. It about your comment

Comment: This is starting to make more sense now, thanks.  I ran 'collectstatic' manually and now I see my static files copied to the `staticfiles` directory.  What's weird is that when I run `runserver`, the `staticfiles` directory gets created but not populated.  Maybe it's not running the same command.

Comment: If you're using Heroku, and the django_heroku module, and you're calling django_heroku.settings(), then a staticfiles directory will be created, regardless of your STATIC_ROOT setting.