# django's collectstatic collects into unexpected directory

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to upload my staticfiles to amazon s3 storage, but I can't stop django from just putting them in a directory *staticfiles* in the project root. I have boto3 in my requirements.txt and have set

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I have successfully set up s3 with media files, to the same bucket (under different directory).

Collectstatic also seems disregards the STATIC_ROOT variable in settings.py when I comment out the s3-settings. When running python3 manage.py collectstatic I expect it to gather static files into STATIC_ROOT as it says in the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/ (under static_root). But even if I give a different value to STATIC_ROOT, collectstatic always collects into a directory on the root called *staticfiles*.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'this_is_not_used_by_collectstatic')
```

The rest of my s3 settings:

```
# Amazon S3 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket_name'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'eu-north-1'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

# media
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'korvir.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

Comment: Are you using `django_heroku` by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889463/django-staticfiles-directory-keeps-getting-created#comment92516303_49889463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `django-heroku` and and you have the following in your code, as per the instructions:

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

... then it will overwrite your `STATIC_ROOT` setting. If you want to preserve your own `STATIC_ROOT` setting, then make sure you set `STATIC_ROOT` *after* calling `django_heroku.settings`.

Comment: I should have been more clear, it still ignores STATIC_ROOT even if I comment out the STATICFILES_STORAGE.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for clarifying. Could you please double-check to make sure that there is only *one* `STATIC_ROOT = ` statement in your settings file?

Comment: There is only the one entry

Comment: Ok, let's see whether the setting is being overwritten, or whether it's being ignored. Open a Django shell by running `python manage.py shell`, then import settings, and print out the value of `STATIC_ROOT` with `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.STATIC_ROOT)`.

Comment: this prints the path to the directory _staticfiles_

Comment: So it seems that your `STATIC_ROOT` setting is being overwritten somewhere. Django itself wouldn't do this, so it's either in your project code, or in a 3rd party library. Could you please add your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to you question? Do you split up your settings across multiple files? Is there anywhere in your code that `STATIC_ROOT` may be getting set?

Comment: ah, the problem was `django_heroku.settings(locals())` (my hosting provider is heroku). When I moved `STATIC_ROOT` to the last line in settings.py it worked! Which is a bit strange since they specifically say to put `django_heroku.settings(locals())` last in the file. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, quite strange! I will update my answer so that future visitors can see the solution more plainly. Cheers!